# Result Error: unexpected end of JSON input on executing terraform module

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to fetch secret stored in vault as part of this activity, there is a main.tf file that is in turn executing/calling a shell script. Jenkins pipeline is being used as orchestrator.

During the build I'm encountering an error:

```
Error: Unexpected External Program Results

  on .terraform/modules/hashivault_password/main.tf line 2, in data "external" "vault_token":
   2:   program = ["sh", "${path.module}/vault_login.sh"]

The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.

Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.

Program: /usr/bin/sh
Result Error: unexpected end of JSON input
```

Snippet of main.tf file:

```
data "external" "vault_token" {
  program = ["sh", "${path.module}/vault_login.sh"]
  query = {
    vault_address  = var.vault_address
    vault_namespace = var.vault_namespace
  }
}
data "vault_generic_secret" "vault_auth" {
  path = var.vault_secret_path
}
```

Snippet of Shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e
eval "$(jq -r '@sh "vault_address=\(.vault_address) vault_namespace=\(.vault_namespace)"')"
export no_proxy=$( echo "$vault_address" | sed -e 's#^https://##; s#:.*##' )
VAULT_TOKEN=$(/usr/local/bin/vault login -token-only -address="${vault_address}" -namespace="${vault_namespace}" -method=aws)
```

Tried to parse the output using jq